# child elements in grouped list sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a created a grouped list in sencha touch 2.
I want to find the child elements under a group header,on the click of the header.
I have written the following code

```
for(i=0;i<groups.length;i++){
        if(groups[i].name==index.innerHTML){
        for(j=0;j<groups[i].children.length;j++){
            a[j]=groups[i].children[j].data.rootNodeName;
            console.log("length",groups[i].children[j].data.rootNodeName);
            console.log("a[j]",a[j]);   

        }

        }
    }
```

is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: Use Ext.ComponentQuery: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery